# Comparing input values with csv file in Python 3.4

Tags: python, csv

I've got a simple question but I can't really find a right solution for that.

I have a csv file that contains students' names and subjects for which they are registered:
name,subject1,subject2,subject3
Student1,MN1,MN2,MN3
Student2,BN1,BN2,BN3
Student3,MN4,MN5,MN6

Student needs to enter his name and subject name in order to check whether he is registered or not for this subject

My code:

```
import csv

Name = input("Please provide your name: ")
Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")

with open('students.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (row['name'] == Name and row['subject1'] == Subject or 
row['subject2'] == Subject or row['subject3'] == Subject):
            print ("You are registered. It won't take long to run your VM")
        else:
            print ("You are not registered")
```

My problem is that it gives multiple outputs to me
Output:
Please provide your name: Student3
Please provide your Subject: MN4
You are not registered
You are not registered
You are registered. It won't take long to run your VM

Obviously, it should be just: 
You are registered. It won't take long to run your VM

Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Note that `for` loops in Python have an optional `else` clause that will execute when the loop ends without a `break` statement...

Your code prints each iteration of the loop. What you want is to print only at the end of the loop...

```
with open('students.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if (row['name'] == Name and (row['subject1'] == Subject or row['subject2'] == Subject or row['subject3'] == Subject)):
            print("You are registered. It won't take long to run your VM")
            break
    else:
        print("You are not registered")
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works but not for the last iteration, it stops after the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

I believe a dictionary will work best for you:

```
import csv

data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))}

Name = input("Please provide your name: ")
Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")

if Subject in data[Name]:
    print("you are registered")
else:
    print("you are not registered")
```

Comment: data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('filename.csv'))} - could you please explain this line? 
Thank you, it works.

Comment: @Ruslan that line is called dictionary comprehension. It takes each line from your csv file and creates a dictionary key with the first element, `i[0]`. Then, the value for this dictionary is created by using list slicing, which mutates `i` by keeping the right-half of the list, starting from the second element.

Comment: Thank you!
I've got another question if you don't mind 
I am adding a second csv file that needs to be used if name and subject are matching ...so I need to add another dictionary for the second csv file?

Comment: @Ruslan  actually it depends. You can use another dictionary; however, you could also use `zip()` to iterate over the contents of both. Please post a sample of your second csv file and detail what you would like done with it.

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe will be a good structure to store you csv file. Please give it a read [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html), anyway coming to your code. Please refer the below code.

Please install pandas and numpy for this

```
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("testing.csv")

Name = input("Please provide your name: ")
Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")

query = '(name == '+ '\'' + Name + '\'' + ') and (subject1 == '+ '\'' \
         + Subject + '\'' + ' or subject2 == ' + '\'' + Subject + '\'' \
         + ' or subject2 == ' + '\'' + Subject + '\')'

if df.query(query).empty:
    print ("You are registered. It won't take long to run your VM")
else:
    print ("You are not registered")
```

**Reference:**

1. [pandas query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)